# Choosing router transition in Angular Ionic 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-routing, ionic6

I'm using Ionic 6 with Angular and sometimes Ionic includes some nice animation when transitioning between routes. Can I choose which animation will be used when I navigate using `route.navigate(['path'])`? Is it possible to choose it from the default Ionic animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic provides default animations for both iOS & Android.

Instead of using `route.navigate(['path'])`, You can use `NavController` methods. Basically, it uses Angular's router with explicit direction. Ionic will animate this transition for you.

```
// imports
import { NavController } from "@ionic/angular";

constructor(
  private navCtrl: NavController,
){ }

// example usage with forward route
this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['path']);
```

Comment: I think this option is actually deprecated in ionic 6. Following [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration#navigation) from the documentation of ionic, angular router should be used instead of NavController

Comment: Hi, I believe you misread this.
The documentation refers to migrating to Ionic4 from older versions. 
Since Ionic 4, Ionic NavController also uses Angular's router instead of its own custom navigation implementation.